# Asterisk: customised log using agi

Tags: asterisk, agi

Is there anyway to get customized log in asterisk by using agi, log file with csv format will contains only those informations :

-date of the call
-Caller id
-Called number

Answer (score 0):

Use the asterisk  [Call Details Recording (CDR)](http://www.asteriskdocs.org/en/3rd_Edition/asterisk-book-html-chunk/asterisk-SysAdmin-SECT-1.html).

You should use [cdr_custom.conf](http://www.asteriskguru.com/tutorials/cdr_custom_conf.html) to generate a custom CDR for every finished call, this file defines what exactly gets logged in this CDR line.